# How to compute growth rate across lines in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I've been struggling with an issue in R.
I have a dataframe with yearly data (the year is an int).
Here it is:

```
    year  total
 1  1991   955.
 2  1992  2947.
 3  1993  7005.
 4  1994  7454.
 5  1995 28542.
 6  1996 21160.
 7  1997 52374.
 8  1998 57506.
 9  1999 90078.
10  2000 71042.
```

My goal is to compute the growth rate for each year starting from 1992 but I cannot find anyway to do it. Using `dplyr` and its `mutate` function, I cannot access the data of the previous row and therefore cannot compute the growth rate. I thought about a loop iterating over the whole dataframe but I am sure that there is a simpler and more elegant way to do it.

In brief, here are my 2 questions:

1. How to compute the growth rate?
2. Is it possible to include only certain rows in this computation or does the dataframe need to be filtered out beforehand?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you considered writing a loop to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like below?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    growth = round(((total - lag(total)) / lag(total)) * 100, 2)
  )
```

Output:

```
   year total growth
1  1991   955     NA
2  1992  2947 208.59
3  1993  7005 137.70
4  1994  7454   6.41
5  1995 28542 282.91
6  1996 21160 -25.86
7  1997 52374 147.51
8  1998 57506   9.80
9  1999 90078  56.64
10 2000 71042 -21.13
```

About your question, of course you can include only certain data, but the exact answer would depend on what you'd like to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not hear of the lag function before.